# jQuery load map html into div from url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try loading like:

```
$('#map').load(url + ' #map', function () {

});
```

Probably map div is not loaded, when jQuert try load this ? How to solve that ?

For example my page is `example.com/map` in that page I have map ant markers, when I do some actions I want load map from `example.com/map?city=Oslo` When I load from that url I get empty div without map.

Comment: can you be a more descriptive ?

Comment: If that is the issue then add your codes in ready block `$( document ).ready(function() {});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation of `jQuery.load()`([Link](http://api.jquery.com/load/)), by following lines:

> When this method executes, it retrieves the content of ajax/test.html,
>   but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with
>   an ID of container. This element, along with its contents, is inserted
>   into the element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved
>   document is discarded.

I understand that, container with id **map** will be present in the ajax response and hence when you try to load it in `$("#map")`, the container itself is not present.

You may try like(as given in doc):-

`$("#some_other_id").load(url + "#map");`